# LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble. But I have it in preamble

Tags: pdftex, subfiles

```
! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.
```

All my `\usepackage` commands begin before `\begin{document}` and I still get this error? :(

This happened when I tried to add a `subfiles` package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal example code reproducting the error message?

Comment: Below that message (after the reference to the LaTeX manual) should be the line where the error occurred. That should tell you which command caused the problem and the corresponding line number. (There are other commands, aside from `\usepackage`, that are only allowed in the preamble.)

Comment: The very second line caused the problem: the one where I set up the language of the document: \usepackage[language]{babel}

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments, and in any case, the question, as it stands, is unanswerable.

Comment: It is not solved at all! It is not unanswerable. It's sad that you can't help, but maybe leave it to smarter people to answer it?